# How do I make the first line of text indent without it throwing everything else off?

Tags: html, css

I would like to indent the text as I have done with the second heading `WORK EXPERIENCE` but if I apply this class to the first line 'EDUCATION' it throws out all my columns, how can I avoid this?

code:

```css
.indent {
  text-indent: 70px;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <p>EDUCATION<br> 2014-18 Massey University Wellington, New Zealand. Bachelor of Design, Honours First Class. Visual Communication Design.<br></p>
  <div class="indent">
    <p>WORK EXPERIENCE<br>
  </div>
```

Comment: You can add the class to `p` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use you markup you can wrap the indented text by your class.

**HTML**

```
    <div class="column">
        <p><span class="indent">EDUCATION</span>
            2014-18 Massey University Wellington, New Zealand. Bachelor of Design, Honours First Class. Visual Communication Design.
        </p>
        <p><span class="indent">WORK EXPERIENCE</span></p>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.indent{
    text-indent: 70px;
    display:block; /* Added to force the span acting as a block to avoid <br> tag*/
    /*word-break: break-word; I don´t think you need this property. */
}
```

**My Suggestion**

```
<!-- The H3 heading it´s a suggestion, and you can always chose from the H1 -  H6 dependeng on your needs -->
<div class="column">
    <h3 class="indent">Education</h3> 
    <p>2014-18 Massey University Wellington, New Zealand. Bachelor of Design, Honours First Class. Visual Communication Design.</p>
    <h3 class="indent">Work Experience</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla tempus elit tellus, dapibus cursus orci.</p>
</div>

.indent{
    text-indent: 70px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    display:block; /* This one is optional in the suggested markup.*/
}
```

Comment: Alright!!!! Can i suggest a better markup for you, a bit more simpler? :)

Comment: Out of interest if you want it to be a block why use a `span` rather than a `div`?

Comment: It´s all about semantic... IMO it´s more correct use a span, inside a <p> tag than a div. The results it´s the same, but the span it´s a neutral tag like div, but normally it´s used inside inline elements.

Comment: You can have a nice answer here - http://htmldog.com/guides/html/intermediate/spandiv/

Answer (score 0):

Close the p element after EDUCATION word and then the indentation will apply only to the heading line and not to all block of text.

```
<div class="column">
     <p class="indent">EDUCATION</p>
     <p>2014-18 Massey University
          Wellington, New Zealand.
          Bachelor of Design, Honours
          First Class. Visual Communication Design.<br></p>
      <div class ="indent">
      <p>WORK EXPERIENCE<br>
            </div>
```

Comment: This seems logical has made no change

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="column">
    <p class="indent">EDUCATION
        <br />
        2014-18 Massey University Wellington, New Zealand. Bachelor of Design, Honours First Class. Visual Communication
        Design.
        <br />
    </p>
    <div class="indent">
        <p>WORK EXPERIENCE</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will work and you will get output as 
[image]

I guess, I am understanding your question correctly

Comment: thats exactly the result I want but I applied your changes and it hasn't worked for me

Comment: It should've worked. Coz, it's not that complicated. Can you edit the question with your current code? Let me check

Comment: Ahh you are right, it works when I put that section of code alone in code pen so there must be some other code blocking it, https://codepen.io/alex-burger/pen/yjxJBY

Answer (score 0):

Try this below. There is no need to use br tags instead you can add margin bottom to the p element. See the CSS class rules below.

CSS

```
.indent {
  text-indent: 70px;
  word-break: break-word;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="column">
   <p class="indent">EDUCATION</p>
   <p>2014-18 Massey University Wellington, New Zealand. 
      Bachelor of Design, Honours First Class. Visual 
      Communication Design.
   </p>
</div>
```

JSFiddle sample link

```
https://jsfiddle.net/k1vjvkt7/
```